# Ubuntu Server 20.04 running Apache2 Webserver; Possible DNS issue?

Tags: apache2, dns, webserver

I have a rather unique problem, or at least, I haven't been able to find an answer after a couple days of troubleshooting.

I am running a Windows 10 host with two Virtual Machines: One is Ubuntu Server 20.04 and the other VM is Kali 2021.1. I have the Ubuntu server set up with Apache2 as a webserver. I followed [this guide](https://linuxhint.com/install_apache_web_server_ubuntu/) to the letter, and according to it, everything is set up properly. If I open a browser and navigate to the IP address (10.0.0.36) the website displays fine. Navigating to http://info.net fails. However, if I go to http://ubuntu-server (the name of the server) it displays the website correctly.

I'm at a complete loss for why it won't work with the correct URL (http://info.net). I'm reasonably sure it's a DNS issue, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome, `ubuntu-server` is the local name of the server, it's equivalent to the ip. Look at the guide you mention *"We will set up the domain name “info.net”. **Make sure to replace the info.ne with your own domain name**"*.

Comment: Is **info.net** the actual name of your domain? Because the site http://info.net does exist and opens some search engine. What is the actual domain name you registered for that server (did you register any at all)? You must use the actual domain name. **info.net** in the guide you mentioned was just an example.

Comment: Thank you both. I should have mentioned, this is intended to be a private webserver internal to my home network. For this reason, I have not registered a domain name. However, I do not have an internal DNS server, so I have my DNS all pointing to google's server (8.8.8.8). Is that the issue perhaps? Sorry for what is probably a really dumb question. I am fairly new to all of this.